# I want to create txt file of batch file result

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am trying to copy a file from one drive to other drive; it's working but I need its result in a .txt file.  For this I wrote this command, but while it makes the file when manually run, when I run that file via the Task Scheduler it doesn't make the .txt file.

```
@echo on
(
copy W:\DUMP\UATDP-%date:~7,2%.DMP  F:\DP_DUMP\UATDP-%date:~7,2%.DMP /Y
 copy W:\DUMP\IUATDP-%date:~7,2%.DMP  F:\DP_DUMP\IUATDP-%date:~7,2%.DMP  /Y

) > LOG_COPY-%date:~7,2%.TXT
```

Can any one help me with this task?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the working directory. When you manually execute the batch file yourself, you're executing it from the directory the batch file exists in. Without specifying the working directory, the task scheduler is going to execute it from its own working directory. (As a side note, that probably means you've got some text files sitting in the task scheduler's working directory)

To user [PetSerAl](https://superuser.com/users/364455/petseral)'s point, the simplest method would be to add the full file path for the .txt file you're attempting to save, whether it's to the same folder as the batch, or to your desktop, or to a logfile directory.

Alternatives would be to add a `cd` line to change the directory immediately before saving the file, or to use `pushd` if you really want to unnecessarily complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line:

```
) > LOG_COPY-%date:~7,2%.TXT
```

Just replace this to

```
) > D:\logs\log_copy_%date:~7,2%.txt
```